# zsh: abort python error when I try to run the app in venv

Tags: python, zsh, python-venv, zshrc, pyenv

I setup Python 3.6 using `pyenv` so I could manage multiple Python versions (e.g. 3.7 and 3.8) in the future. I didn't use Homebrew to install Python since it changes the system version. It's my first time to use `zsh` shell since it's the default shell in Catalina OS. Currently, I use 3.6.8 version for my existing project.

So here's my current setup:

`% pyenv versions`

result:

```
  system
* 3.6.8 (set by /Users/macbook/.python-version)
  3.7.3
```

`% python -V` results to `Python 3.6.8`

`% which python` results to `/Users/macbook/.pyenv/shims/python`

`% echo $PATH` results to `/Users/macbook/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

The content of my `~/.zshrc` is `PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH`

I created a virtual env using `% python -m venv venv`, installed all the necessary packages, and when I activate it and get the python path,

```
(venv) % python -V
Python 3.6.8

(venv) % which python
/Users/macbook/python-project/venv/bin/python

(venv) % echo $PATH
/Users/macbook/python-project/venv/bin:/Users/macbook/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Finally, when I try to run the app, I always get `zsh: abort` error:

```
(venv) % python app.py
zsh: abort      python app.py

(venv) % export FLASK_APP=app.py
(venv) % flask run
zsh: abort      flask run
```

I don't know what else is still missing or are there anything wrong with my python path?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for you to use anaconda?

Comment: @NavanK. I haven't used it yet but I might as well try it in my next projects. Can you recommend the best site that gives a good strategy to set it up alongside my other package management?

Comment: https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/01-Orientation/01.03-Installing-Anaconda-on-Windows/      is the one I would prefer. However , you might want to look into Youtube videos as per your requirements. Anaconda will also help you set up multiple environments for your needs.

Comment: Anaconda has nothing to do with your problem. (Also conda is the environment manager, not anaconda, which is a distribution of Python that comes with conda and certain Python packages). Why do you think this is a path issue? Don't your steps clearly show your path is fine? Have you tried using bash instead to launch your program? I would assume `zsh: abort` means the program threw a `SIGABRT` signal.

Comment: On macOs to get more insights why the Python process crashed you can open the Console app and look at the crash reports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching through the web, I think this is a common issue with the latest MacOS or Homebrew. This [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/119429) fixed the issue.

1. `brew update && brew upgrade && brew install openssl`
2. copy the two files from /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1g to /usr/local/lib/

   `cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1g/`

   `sudo cp libssl.1.1.1.dylib libcrypto.1.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/`
3. add symlink to missing openssl libs

   `cd /usr/local/lib`

   `sudo ln -s libssl.1.1.1.dylib libssl.dylib`

   `sudo ln -s libcrypto.1.1.1.dylib libcrypto.dylib`

Answer (score 1):

For me, the below worked:

Python 3.6.9
MacOs Catalina 10.15.7

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1h/
cp lib/libssl.1.1.dylib lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s libssl.1.1.dylib libssl.dylib
sudo ln -s libcrypto.1.1.dylib libcrypto.dylib
```

Thanks to the answer by Zhanrah