# Mac m1 pyodbc.connect causes zsh: abort

Tags: python, pyodbc, apple-m1, apple-silicon

When I run `pyodbc.connect(...)` my python crashes and I get `zsh: abort` error in terminal.

Running:

- Mac M1 Pro Monterey
- Python 3.8.9

Installed MS ODBC drivers (tried 17 and 18).

Tried running in base Python and virtual environments.

In base python, I get the following system error:

---

### Translated Report (Full Report Below)

Process:               Python [1869]
Path:                  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            com.apple.python3
Version:               3.8.9 (3.8.9)
Build Info:            python3-103000000000000~1538
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [611]
Responsible:           Terminal [80951]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-03-08 17:42:55.3063 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 12.2.1 (21D62)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        919246FC-3C09-6151-CCAB-05C65A4A9B63

Sleep/Wake UUID:       4CFF985F-843A-4C63-ABC8-97435300AADE

Time Awake Since Boot: 370000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2014 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
stack buffer overflow

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18ff659b8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18ff98eb0 pthread_kill + 288
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x18fed63a0 __abort + 128
3   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x18fec818c __stack_chk_fail + 96
4   pyodbc.cpython-38-darwin.so            0x102c4f5d4 GetErrorFromHandle(Connection*, char const*, void*, void*) + 1024
5   pyodbc.cpython-38-darwin.so            0x102c4f188 RaiseErrorFromHandle(Connection*, char const*, void*, void*) + 16
6   pyodbc.cpython-38-darwin.so            0x102c48cf0 Connection_New(_object*, bool, bool, long, bool, _object*, Object&) + 1324
7   pyodbc.cpython-38-darwin.so            0x102c54b34 mod_connect(_object*, _object*, _object*) + 1468
8   Python3                                0x103185968 cfunction_call_varargs + 140
9   Python3                                0x103185368 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 372
10  Python3                                0x1032523fc call_function + 448
11  Python3                                0x10324f800 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23692
12  Python3                                0x1032532e4 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3048
13  Python3                                0x103249ae0 PyEval_EvalCode + 60
14  Python3                                0x10328f384 PyRun_InteractiveOneObjectEx + 712
15  Python3                                0x10328e92c PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 156
16  Python3                                0x10328e84c PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 72
17  Python3                                0x1032ac808 Py_RunMain + 2120
18  Python3                                0x1032acb1c pymain_main + 340
19  Python3                                0x1032acb98 Py_BytesMain + 40
20  dyld                                   0x1029ed0f4 start + 520

---

(this is just a small extract of the report because I can't figure out how to "embed" the full report in a scrollable object in my post)

I have tried [zsh: abort python error when I try to run the app in venv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63080383/zsh-abort-python-error-when-i-try-to-run-the-app-in-venv)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If anyone comes across this as well, I have since resorted to ```pymssql``` which magically worked.